# ag and rg not listing files starting with underline, find does

Tags: bash, macos, ag, ripgrep

If I do:

```
touch _gandalf
```

---

And then:

```
rg --files | grep gandalf | wc -l
```

or

```
ag -l -g "" | grep gandalf | wc -l
```

I get `0` matches as result.

---

Now if I do a `touch gandaf` I get `1` match.

Why is that? Does files starting with underline have a similar behaviour as hidden files? Maybe is something on mac's filesystem? As mentioned on the title if I replace ag/rg for `find .` it works as expected.

Comment: Did you check your `~/.ignore`, `~/.agignore`, `~/.rgignore` files?

Comment: It was my global .gitignore :/

Comment: ripgrep has a `--debug` flag that will tell you exactly why a file is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was my global `.gitignore` having a clausule to exclude files starting with underlines.

But I think is useful to keep in all this files (as mentioned on the comments):

.gitignore

.ignore

.rgignore

.agignore